# Does the CSP header needs to be on every asset of your site?

Tags: http-headers, content-security-policy

I searched on the internet but could not find the answer.

Does a CSP header needs to be on every asset on your site or is it enough it is on 1 (or a few more) asset for a browser to follow the CSP directives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be on each HTML response, it does not need to be on other assets such as images or icons. Depending on how you are hosting your site, this should be configurable at the global level (ie. IIS, you can add global headers to your web.config)